# Wowza error :Failed to play myStream; stream not found.

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp, wowza

i am using ffmpeg for encoding a video which will then be restreamed using wowza.i am new to streaming.first i started wowza using command

/etc/init.d/WowzaMediaServer start

after that i start streaming a MP4 file using rtsp protocol.i used the command

ffmpeg -re -i /usr/local/WowzaMediaServer/content/sample.mp4 -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec libx264 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://myuser:mypassword@127.0.0.1:1935/live/myStream.sdp

video start streaming before all of these i changed admin.password and added a username as myuser and password as mypassword when i run above command its streaming but after that they say go to

WowzaMediaServer/examples/LiveVideoStreaming/FlashRTMPPlayer/Player.html

and fill server with  rtmp://localhost:1935/live

and Stream field with myStream

when i click on connect its giving me status

"Failed to play myStream; stream not found."

i am following this article http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?354-How-to-set-up-live-streaming-using-an-RTSP-RTP-based-encoder

where i am wrong i dont know.i am unable to figure it out. from wowza support team i am not getting satisfactory answers .so someone work on wowza please help me!!why i am not able to connect my video stream to wowza.Please respond stuck badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears there are some basic issues with the rtsp from ffmpeg and then no matches to the play request

You have

ffmpeg -re -i /usr/local/WowzaMediaServer/content/sample.mp4 -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec libx264 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://myuser:mypassword@127.0.0.1:1935/live/myStream.sdp

You need to make sure your ffmpeg has libx264 and libfdk_aac plugins available. You should be able to determine this with just

ffmpeg

and it should print out the libraries available.

If you have all the libraries then you are publishing a stream called

myStream.sdp

You then have instructions that say

and fill server with rtmp://localhost:1935/live

and Stream field with myStream

So you should either change your ffmpeg command to

ffmpeg -re -i /usr/local/WowzaMediaServer/content/sample.mp4 -acodec libfdk_aac -vcodec libx264 -f rtsp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://myuser:mypassword@127.0.0.1:1935/live/myStream

Note no .sdp in the stream name any more or use a Stream field in the player of

myStream.sdp

When publishing a stream and then attempting to play it back they must match, otherwise you get back Stream Not Found.

Comment: thanks a lot for help sincerely stuck with this very badly thanks again

Answer (score 0):

One way to successfully do this is to specify only the port number (65000 in this example), making sure it isn't 1935 and server in your ffmpeg command then create a mystream.stream file in your content directory of your Wowza server with ONLY the following line: 
`udp://0.0.0:65000`

Then, in Wowza/conf/startupstreams.xml, add the following:

```
          <!-- Native RTP example (SDP file is myStream.sdp) -->
            <StartupStream>
                    <Application>live/_definst_</Application>
                    <MediaCasterType>rtp</MediaCasterType>
                    <StreamName>mystream.stream</StreamName>
            </StartupStream>
```

Restart wowza and ffmpeg and then re-try your url in with the stream name mystream.stream.

Comment: i agree with your point i run that previously but i want to stream it with rtsp protocol i have to make an Android application which accept streaming using rtsp protocol so i hope u got my point.

Comment: OK - if it helps, the setup I described uses rtp.  The vlc command is something like: cvlc --sout '#transcode{},width=640,height=360,venc=x264{profile=baseline,level=3.0,preset=ultrafast,min-keyint=50,keyint=70,fps=30}}:rtp{mux=ts,dst=domain.com,port=65000}'